# How can i select a photo of index 3 in a gridView using appium?

Tags: java, android, appium

I'm using appium to automated an already installed app on my device.

(I didn't write it, and it's not my apk).

After a starting splash activity, comes the main activity with a photo grid view.

After I enter this activity, how can i select a photo of index 3 in a gridView?

[image]

I have tried:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.ImageView"));

WebElement element = elements.get(1);
```

but didn't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can filter it by index. Try this:

```
driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.ImageView' and @index='3']");
```